# Set password specifications for SimpleMembership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

Looking into the MVC4 template and one thing I'm struggling to find is where to specify (if you can) the password requirements.  Mainly I'm wanting to remove the requirement of a non-alphanum char.

Is this something that is possible to do in `SimpleMembership`?

EDIT:

(What are the specifications that you can apply to `SimpleMembership`?)

Comment: I'm looking for the same answer...

Answer (score 1):

After looking into the [SimpleMembershipProvider](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9306b6dba83a0c18e01716f8065aaf6524307a75#src/WebMatrix.WebData/SimpleMembershipProvider.cs)...I've been able to determine that the way it is currently implemented leaves you completely on your own to manage password requirements.

```
        public override int MinRequiredPasswordLength
        {
            get { return InitializeCalled ? 0 : PreviousProvider.MinRequiredPasswordLength; }
        }

        public override int MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters
        {
            get { return InitializeCalled ? 0 : PreviousProvider.MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters; }
        }
```

As you can see, by default it returns 0 unless you have another [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) configured such as [SqlMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx)...which I think kind of defeats the purpose of using the [SimpleMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)...at least in my mind.

This has driven me to consider [Brock Allen's advice](http://brockallen.com/2012/09/02/think-twice-about-using-membershipprovider-and-simplemembership/) and look into using his [MembershipReboot](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot) which can be [installed using nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot/). His github page has a great sample mvc site which shows how to use his library. I haven't used it before...and am currently trying it out...but from what I've seen and read so far, it looks great...and has left me wondering why more people haven't decided to use it over the SimpleMembershipProvider.

Comment: I'm guessing it's not being used due to not being known (I had never heard of it).  On a side note I've implemented SimpleMembershipProvider and it has been incredibly "simple" if you can work within it's quirks.  The project I'm using it for...simple is more important to me then the...how I want it.  As long as it securely provides/restricts access to the site that was really all I cared about.

Comment: Also, I agree that it defeats the purpose to implement it the way it is now.... making it incredibly difficult to change things.